# Numbers Mac Link Date Cells

Tags: mac, numbers

I would like to link cells formatted as dates together so that I can change the date in one cell and have all the  dates change to go in order from that date. So if I format the cells to go from Jan 1 2023 to Jan 31 2023, I'd like to be able to change Jan 1 2023 to Jan 1 2024 and the rest of the cells change to that year automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I put this into B1:

```
=A1+365
```

When cell A1 has 1 Jan 2023 in it.

So if you change A1 to 1 Jan 2024, then B1 will become 1 Jan 2025 and so on.

This works because the dates are actually stored as a serial number representing days, so adding x days like 30 or 31 will give the next month.

[image]

Do check out the date functions like month etc that exist which can make other tasks easier.